# Node.js returning JSON as file

Tags: json, api, node.js

I'm writing a node.js app and the most curious thing is happening when I try to get data from a third party API. I get teh JSON result as a file. in console it outs the text correctly, but when I hit it from the browser it downloads a file with json string in it. I've tried doing JSON.stringify but that just prints out hex I believe.

How do I tell node.js to output the contents of the result to the browser?

```
    https.get({ host: 'api.bookshare.org', path: '/book/searchFTS/"+keyword+"/page/1/limit/250/format/json?api_key=2msxgk595nke8rhwmbzh8sut' }, function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  });

}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

Comment: remember about appropriate headers (`application/json`) for JSON files. Your browser may treat those files as downloadable.

Comment: Yes stupid me. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome was treating the content-type header text/json as a file. Setting it to text/plain did the trick.